# in a rails app, I have a route that does not work in https and gives a 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, http-status-code-404

I have a rails app. One of my routes only works in http and not in https. In https I get an 404 page not found error. The rest of the site works fine for both http and https. I'm not sure how to proceed in debugging/resolving this issue.

http://my.rails.app/mypage (works fine)

https://my.rails.app/mypage (404 page not found)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `config.force_ssl = true` in your environment configuration.

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = true
  end
end
```

You can also selectively enable https depending on the current Rails environment. For example, you might want to keep HTTPS turned off on development, and enable it on staging/production.

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = false
  end
end

# config/environments/production.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```